# Does the DSLR camera's body (Canon EOS700D and EOS 6D) makes difference in image quality, when using the Canon Macro 100mm f2.8L USM?

Tags: product-photography, macro-lenses, canon-6d, canon-700d, jewelry

Does the DSLR camera's body (Canon EOS700D and EOS 6D) makes difference in image quality, when using the Canon Macro lens 100mm f2.8L USM for the jewelry photography?

Comment: What does "image quality" mean to you?

Comment: Note, one is full frame and one no, so the images will be in any case different. Comparing with the EF 60mm macro would be more similar.

Comment: What is the size of the jewels you plan to take pictures of?

Answer (score -1):

No, only because the 6D is a full frame camera, whereas the 700D is a APS-C 1.6x camera.

For jewelry photography I would say go for the 700D, as it would provide 1.6x larger images.

Comment: You say "no" (i.e. the body you use doesn't make a difference), but the rest of your answer seems to contradict that.